# Why is the __dict__ of instances so much smaller in size in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, dictionary, python-internals

In Python, dictionaries created for the instances of a class are tiny compared to the dictionaries created containing the same attributes of that class:

```
import sys

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

f = Foo(20, 30)
```

When using Python 3.5.2, the following calls to `getsizeof` produce:

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(vars(f))  # vars gets obj.__dict__
96 
>>> sys.getsizeof(dict(vars(f))
288
```

*`288 - 96 = 192` bytes saved!*

Using Python 2.7.12, though, on the other hand, the same calls return:

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(vars(f))
280
>>> sys.getsizeof(dict(vars(f)))
280
```

*`0` bytes saved.*

In both cases, the dictionaries obviously have *exactly the same contents*:

```
>>> vars(f) == dict(vars(f))
True
```

so this isn't a factor. Also, this also applies to Python 3 only.

So, what's going on here? Why is the size of the `__dict__` of an instance so tiny in Python 3?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

#### *In short*:

Instance `__dict__`'s are implemented differently than the 'normal' dictionaries created with `dict` or `{}`. The dictionaries of an instance *share* the keys and hashes and the keep a separate array for the parts that differ: the values. `sys.getsizeof` only counts those values when calculating the size for the instance dict.

#### *A bit more*:

Dictionaries in CPython are, as of Python 3.3, implemented in one of two forms:

- **Combined dictionary**: All values of the dictionary are stored alongside the key and hash for each entry. ([`me_value` member of the `PyDictKeyEntry` struct](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5010a77a4da76d8d3fd861a63a7f1ce8f0e9c520/Objects/dict-common.h#L8)). As far as I know, this form is used for dictionaries created with `dict`, `{}` and the module namespace.
- **Split table**: The values are stored *separately* in an array, while the keys and hashes are shared ([Values stored in `ma_values` of `PyDictObject`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5010a77a4da76d8d3fd861a63a7f1ce8f0e9c520/Include/dictobject.h#L27))

Instance dictionaries are *always* implemented in a split-table form (a Key-Sharing Dictionary) which allows instances of a given class to share the keys (and hashes) for their `__dict__` and only differ in the corresponding values.

This is all described in [PEP 412 -- Key-Sharing Dictionary](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0412/). The implementation for the split dictionary landed in Python `3.3` so, previous versions of the `3` family as well as Python `2.x` don't have this implementation.

[The implementation of `__sizeof__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5010a77a4da76d8d3fd861a63a7f1ce8f0e9c520/Objects/dictobject.c#L2602) for dictionaries takes this fact into account and only considers the size that corresponds to the values array when calculating the size for a split dictionary.

It's thankfully, self-explanatory:

```c
Py_ssize_t size, res;

size = DK_SIZE(mp->ma_keys);
res = _PyObject_SIZE(Py_TYPE(mp));
if (mp->ma_values)                    /*Add the values to the result*/
    res += size * sizeof(PyObject*);
/* If the dictionary is split, the keys portion is accounted-for
   in the type object. */
if (mp->ma_keys->dk_refcnt == 1)     /* Add keys/hashes size to res */
    res += sizeof(PyDictKeysObject) + (size-1) * sizeof(PyDictKeyEntry);
return res;
```

As far as I know, split-table dictionaries are *created only for the namespace of instances*, using `dict()` or `{}` (as also described in the PEP) *always* results in a combined dictionary that doesn't have these benefits.

---

As an aside, since it's fun, we can always break this optimization. There's two current ways I've currently found, a silly way or by a more sensible scenario:

1. Being silly:

   ```
   >>> f = Foo(20, 30)
   >>> getsizeof(vars(f))
   96
   >>> vars(f).update({1:1})  # add a non-string key
   >>> getsizeof(vars(f))
   288
   ```

   Split tables only support string keys, adding a non-string key (which really makes **zero** sense) breaks this rule and CPython turns the split table into a combined one loosing all memory gains.
2. A scenario that might happen:

   ```
   >>> f1, f2 = Foo(20, 30), Foo(30, 40)
   >>> for i, j in enumerate([f1, f2]):
   ...    setattr(j, 'i'+str(i), i)
   ...    print(getsizeof(vars(j)))
   96
   288
   ```

   Different keys being inserted in the instances of a class will eventually lead to the split table getting combined. This doesn't apply only to the instances already created; all *consequent* instances created from the class will be have a combined dictionary instead of a split one.

   ```
   # after running previous snippet
   >>> getsizeof(vars(Foo(100, 200)))
   288
   ```

of course, there's no good reason, other than for fun, for doing this on purpose.

---

If anyone is wondering, Python 3.6's dictionary implementation doesn't change this fact. The two aforementioned forms of dictionaries while still available are just further compacted (the implementation of `dict.__sizeof__` also changed, so some differences should come up in values returned from `getsizeof`.)

Comment: great info - can one use those key sharing dicts in pythonland?