# Size of a dictionary in bytes

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to manually calculate a size of a dictionary (number of bytes it occupies in memory). I read that initially it is 280 bytes, at 6th key it increases and then at 86th so on. I want to calculate the size it will occupy when I have more than 10000 keys.

Answer (score 28):

[`sys.getsizeof`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) will help in that case:

```
from sys import getsizeof

dct = {'a': 5, 'b': 7}

print(getsizeof(dct))
```

especially for dictionaries the size will depend on your python version (the implementation has changed recently).

a quick way to create an `N`-sized dictionary is:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
dct = dict(zip_longest(range(N), (), fillvalue=None))
# {0: None, 1: None, 2: None, ....}
```

this should help test your assumptions for your specific python version.

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45284109/why-does-python2-7-dict-use-more-space-than-python3-dict) may be related.

Answer (score 22):

the `sys.getsizeof` not work with nested dict, as shown in the example bellow.

```
>>> import sys
>>> d = { "onj1": {"name":"object 01", "id": "123"},"onj2": {"name":"object 02", "id": "124"}}
>>> d0 = {}
>>> sys.getsizeof(d0)
240
>>> sys.getsizeof(d)
240
```

So the solution found was the function provided by this site:[post](https://goshippo.com/blog/measure-real-size-any-python-object/) OR [github](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bosswissam/a369b7a31d9dcab46b4a034be7d263b2/raw/f99d210019c1fac6bb46d2da81dcdf5ef9932172/pysize.py)

follow the function:

```
import sys

def get_size(obj, seen=None):
    """Recursively finds size of objects"""
    size = sys.getsizeof(obj)
    if seen is None:
        seen = set()
    obj_id = id(obj)
    if obj_id in seen:
        return 0
    # Important mark as seen *before* entering recursion to gracefully handle
    # self-referential objects
    seen.add(obj_id)
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        size += sum([get_size(v, seen) for v in obj.values()])
        size += sum([get_size(k, seen) for k in obj.keys()])
    elif hasattr(obj, '__dict__'):
        size += get_size(obj.__dict__, seen)
    elif hasattr(obj, '__iter__') and not isinstance(obj, (str, bytes, bytearray)):
        size += sum([get_size(i, seen) for i in obj])
    return size
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do a quick check with [`sys.getsizeof()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) (it will return the size of an object in bytes):

```
>>> import sys, itertools
>>> sys.getsizeof(dict(zip(range(1), itertools.cycle([1]))))
280
>>> sys.getsizeof(dict(zip(range(5), itertools.cycle([1]))))
280
>>> sys.getsizeof(dict(zip(range(6), itertools.cycle([1]))))
1048
>>> sys.getsizeof(dict(zip(range(85), itertools.cycle([1]))))
3352
>>> sys.getsizeof(dict(zip(range(86), itertools.cycle([1]))))
12568
>>> sys.getsizeof(dict(zip(range(87), itertools.cycle([1]))))
12568
>>> sys.getsizeof(dict(zip(range(10000), itertools.cycle([1]))))
786712
```

If you are interested in actual inner-workings of Python dictionaries, the [`dictobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/dictobject.c) is the definitive resource ([here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/dictobject.c) for the latest Python 3.6 branch). Also, take a look at [`dictnotes.txt`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/dictnotes.txt).